# Handling Multiple OnClick Events with One Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, boilerplate, redundancy

I created a web form with the following controls:

[image]

Notice that there are 12 buttons, all of which fundamentally do the same thing. Is it possible to have **one** method (not twelve) that handles their `OnClick` event?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Create the event handler and let all the controls call that on `OnClick`.

Comment: Of course, but there will be minimal changes in the code (+ vs -, etc.). How can I address those using `object sender` and `EventArgs e`?

Comment: Could use lambdas and pass in your own modifier: `mySubtractButton.OnClick += (sender, args) => HandleClick(sender, args, Operation.Subtract)`, or wire to a small wrapper method which does it: `myAddButton.Click += (sender, args) => Add(sender, args);`

Comment: You should post the code for a couple of the current OnClick implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just in the object sender part of the event you parse the sender into a TextBox and get the id of the sender in order to know what to do.